# Difference between Information_schema vs sys tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the information_schema tables and sys tables in SQL Server? What are the differences between them?

Comment: `information_schema` *views* provide a rather standardized interface to the metadata.  The `sys` tables/views are specific to SQL Server and contain more proprietary (and complete) information.  I prefer the former for basic information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server difference between catalog views, information schema views vs DMVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195064/sql-server-difference-between-catalog-views-information-schema-views-vs-dmvs)

Comment: @DanGuzman No offense to you, but that linked answer is *terrible*.

Answer (score 33):

Both `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `sys` objects are both metadata catalogs that are available in SQL Server.

The [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` set of views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql) are the ANSI/ISO standard catalogs for metadata.  Most RDBMSs support the majority of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views, and each view exposes essentially identical information regardless of the vendor.  In SQL Server, most, if not all, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are views that go back to the `sys` tables in one way or another.  In SQL Server, you can see the underlying VIEW definitions by running queries like:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'))
```

Which returns:

```
CREATE VIEW INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
AS 
SELECT
    DB_NAME()           AS TABLE_CATALOG,
    s.name              AS TABLE_SCHEMA,
    o.name              AS TABLE_NAME,
    CASE o.type
        WHEN 'U' THEN 'BASE TABLE'
        WHEN 'V' THEN 'VIEW'
    END             AS TABLE_TYPE
FROM
    sys.objects o LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE
    o.type IN ('U', 'V')
```

The [`sys` tables and views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are the original metadata catalog views and tables that were, AFAIK, created by Sybase (Microsoft purchased SQL Server's original code base from them).  Most RDBMSs have an equivalent set of catalog tables, but the specific table names differ between vendors.  In SQL Server, these tables and the later addition of the dynamic management views (DMVs) are what Microsoft created to capture a database's metadata for system and user use.

In SQL Server, since the the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views typically point back to the `sys` tables and due to the ISO definitions for those views, it is not unheard of that [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views do not contain all metadata or all objects that you're looking for](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).  (Personally, I think Aaron's bias in that article is a little overblown, but he's probably been bitten by the issue more than I have, and he also probably works on more complexly configured databases than I do.)

That said, however:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sys.tables'))
```

Returns:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.tables AS
    SELECT o.name, o.object_id, o.principal_id, o.schema_id, o.parent_object_id,
        o.type, o.type_desc, o.create_date, o.modify_date,
        o.is_ms_shipped, o.is_published, o.is_schema_published,
        isnull(ds.indepid, 0) AS lob_data_space_id,
        rfs.indepid AS filestream_data_space_id,
        o.property AS max_column_id_used,
        o.lock_on_bulk_load, o.uses_ansi_nulls, o.is_replicated, o.has_replication_filter,
        o.is_merge_published, o.is_sync_tran_subscribed, o.has_unchecked_assembly_data,
        lob.intprop AS text_in_row_limit,
        o.large_value_types_out_of_row,
        o.is_tracked_by_cdc,
        o.lock_escalation_option AS lock_escalation,
        ts.name AS lock_escalation_desc,
        o.is_filetable,
        o.is_memory_optimized,
        o.durability_option as durability,
        d.name as durability_desc
    FROM sys.objects$ o
    LEFT JOIN sys.sysidxstats lob ON lob.id = o.object_id AND lob.indid <= 1
    LEFT JOIN sys.syssingleobjrefs ds ON ds.depid = o.object_id AND ds.class = 8 AND ds.depsubid <= 1   -- SRC_INDEXTOLOBDS 
    LEFT JOIN sys.syssingleobjrefs rfs ON rfs.depid = o.object_id AND rfs.class = 42 AND rfs.depsubid = 0   -- SRC_OBJTOFSDS
    LEFT JOIN sys.syspalvalues ts ON ts.class = 'LEOP' AND ts.value = o.lock_escalation_option
    LEFT JOIN sys.syspalvalues d ON d.class = 'DOPT' AND d.value = o.durability_option
    WHERE o.type = 'U'
```

This clearly returns much more detailed information, but notice that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` returns both user tables and views, while `sys.tables` only returns user tables.

Personally, I find the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views much better organized and much easier to use for ad hoc queries to find tables by name or columns by name. Still, there are some corner cases where you have to go to the `sys` objects tables, and there are some situations where missing objects in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views can bite you.  If I'm looking for a reliable and complete set of items, then I use the `sys` tables (specifically `sys.objects` or `sys.all_objects`), but those require a lot more work to get readable results.  The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views have done much of that work for you already.

Comment: I was looking for information on performance difference of System (Catalog) Views compared to INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. After checking some relevant Microsoft Docs (e.g. sys.objects) as well as the article mentioned in the answer, and finding no mentions on perf, I deduce the perf is relatively the same. Alt definition check: EXEC sp_helptext [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES]; credit: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72742/ also reveals "I_S" views are based on sys views. So I guess, in theory, sys views might be safer in SQL-Server context. I_S views have good portability / agnostiscm.

Answer (score 0):

**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES** view allows you to get information about all tables and views within a database. By default it will show you this information for every single table and view that is in the database.

Kindly visit this:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/196/informationschematables/

**Sys tables** contain the all-important meta data, the data about your data. This data includes information about table names, column names, and data types, so that SQL Server can properly process queries and return result sets. System tables contain information about valid users and their permissions, so data can be secure, and information about your SQL Server configuration, so you can predict and control the system's behavior.